# How can the settings string for an Azure DSC Extension be programmatically determined

Tags: azure, dsc

I can get a list of extensions in Azure following this article, [adding-extensions-to-azure-vm-in-resource-manager-arm](https://www.schaeflein.net/adding-extensions-to-azure-vm-in-resource-manager-arm). The list is huge:

```
Get-AzureVMAvailableExtension | ft ExtensionName, Publisher
```

I can get some of the detail about an extension:

```
Get-AzureVMAvailableExtension | ?{$_.ExtensionName -eq "VMAccessAgent"}
```

Results:

```
Publisher                   : Microsoft.Compute
ExtensionName               : VMAccessAgent
Version                     : 2.4
Label                       : Windows Azure Json VMAccess Extension for IaaS
Description                 : Windows Azure Json VMAccess Extension for IaaS
PublicConfigurationSchema   : 
PrivateConfigurationSchema  : 
IsInternalExtension         : False
SampleConfig                : 
ReplicationCompleted        : True
Eula                        : 
PrivacyUri                  : 
HomepageUri                 : 
IsJsonExtension             : True
DisallowMajorVersionUpgrade : False
SupportedOS                 : 
PublishedDate               : 5/10/2018 2:28:29 PM
CompanyName                 : Microsoft
Regions                     : All regions
```

However building a PS command to Install the extension eludes me.

```
$settingsString = '{"AntimalwareEnabled":true}'
Set-AzureRmVMExtension `
  -ResourceGroupName "[rgName]" -VMName "[vmName]" `
  -Name "IaasAntimalware" -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Security" `
  -TypeHandlerVersion 1.3 -ExtensionType IaasAntimalware `
  -Location "North Central US" -settingstring $settingsString
```

How am I supposed to know what the settings ($settingsString) of the DSC are ?
I am not looking for information on how to hack is, I know if I go the VM I can find the PS that performs the work. I am looking for a command that will return to me information about the required settings. There are many DSC extensions to  take advantage of, but you have to work too hard to use them. Some kind of logic that can spew settings info would be incredibly useful.

Consider: JsonADDomainExtension, an extension to join a domain. If I poke all over the internet, I can find the parameters required, but I should be able to ask Azure what this extension wants.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way of doing that. Your best bet is to find the extension definition and you will figure out what you need to pass by looking at that, but Azure doesn't offer autocomplete or hints or something of that nature in this regard.